# Can I make Liferea faster?

Tags: liferea

Is there any way to make Liferea faster in fetching feeds from Google Reader? It certainly could be a quality rss reader but in my case it's painfully slow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the **Feed Update Settings** in the **Preferences** and change the default feed interval as in this picture, and consider reading the written **note**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to influence the Google download performance as feeds are downloaded mostly sequentially. The above answer hinting at the update interval will only make updates more frequent, but not faster!